# What is the Scala construct behind self-type annotations?

Tags: scala, self-type

I have a question regarding the following code:

```
  trait Connection {
    def query(q: String): String
  }
  trait Logger {
    def log(l: String): Unit
  }

  trait RequiredServices {
    def makeDatabaseConnection: Connection
    def logger: Logger
  }

  trait TestServices extends RequiredServices {
    def makeDatabaseConnection = new Connection { def query(q: String) = "test" }
    def logger = new Logger { def log(l: String) = println(l) }
  }

  trait ProductFinder { this: RequiredServices =>
    def findProduct(productId: String) = {
      val c = makeDatabaseConnection
      c.query(productId)
      logger.log("querying database..")
    }
  }
  object FinderSystem extends ProductFinder with TestServices
```

My question especially relates to the following portion of code:

```
this: RequiredServices =>
        def findProduct(productId: String) = {
...
```

What is the name of the Scala construct of the above? i.e. the **`this: RequiredServices =>`**

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: In this context it says that `ProductFinder` can access all methods and attributes of `RequiredServices` (as if it extended `RequiredServices`), and that it has to be mixed in with a concrete implementation of `RequiredServices` (in your case, that's `TestServices`) upon instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name is *self type* annotation. It is explained in §5.1 (Templates) of the Scala Language Specification, as follows:

> The sequence of template statements may be prefixed with a formal parameter definition and an arrow, e.g. *x* =>, or *x:T* =>. If a formal parameter is given, it can be used as an alias for the reference **this** throughout the body of the template. If the formal parameter comes with a type *T*, this definition affects the *self type S* of the underlying class or object as follows: Let *C* be the type of the class or trait or object defining the template. If a type *T* is given for the formal self parameter, *S* is the greatest lower bound of *T* and *C*. If no type *T* is given, *S* is just *C*. Inside the template, the type of **this** is assumed to be *S*.
>
> The self type of a class or object must conform to the self types of all classes which are inherited by the template *t*.
>
> A second form of self type annotation reads just **this:** *S* =>. It prescribes the type *S* for **this** without introducing an alias name for it.

Comment: At the end of the section for 2.4 in the Change Log appendix, it's explained that the syntax replaces "requires." You see the old syntax in the cake paper section 2.3 http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/papers/ScalableComponent.html